# Rendering a list of users that only belong to particular account in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm building an application with several levels of permission/access using pundit. I've got users with roles of admin, teacher, and student.

I give admins the ability to create a classroom and in that form they need to select the teacher for that classroom. The selector should list only the teachers(users) who are apart of that school. The problem is that it's listing all the users in the Data Base with the role of teacher.

How do I show only the teachers that belong to that school?

Here's the form

```
   <% if user.school.teachers %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :teacher_id %>
          <%= f.text_field :teacher_id, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Here's my school Model

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :classrooms

validates_uniqueness_of :code

    def students
      self.users.students
    end

    def teachers
       self.users.teachers
    end

    def admins
       self.users.admins
    end
end
```

classroom model

```
class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :school
belongs_to :teacher, :class_name => "User"
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

has_many :pins
has_many :reflections


validates_presence_of :school
validates_presence_of :teacher
validates :code, :uniqueness => { :scope => :school_id }


end
```

Comment: I think you're better to use a `select` instead of a `text_field`: `f.select :teacher_id, options_for_select(user.school.teachers.map{ |t| [t.name, t.id] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Calibou's answer, in your controller for the classroom, call your teachers method to pass a list to the view.

```
def new
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @teachers = @school.teachers
end
```

then for your form:

```
<% if @teachers.present? %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select(:teacher_id, @teachers, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Check out collection_select [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you ! that was the answer! I appreciate your help!

Comment: You're very welcome! Keep at it, stackoverflow is a friendly place!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understand about your problem :

In your school model, `self.users` lists all the users who belong to a school. So we need, in order to get only teachers, to filter this list by saying "I only want users with the teacher status".

So, when you write `self.user.teachers`, it looks for the `teachers` method in your User model. And I guess this method doesn't do what you want.

I think this is where you might have a bug, can you edit your post by adding your User model in order to be sure ?